# Elasticsearch - NEST - Upsert

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have the following two classes

**Entry**

```
public class Entry
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Data> Data { get; set; }
}
```

**EntryData**

```
public class EntryData
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public object Data { get; set; }
}
```

I have a bunch of different applications that produces messages to a queue that I then consume in a separate application to store that data in elasticsearch.

Im using a CorrelationId for all the messages and I want to use this ID as the ID in elasticsearch.
So given the following data:

```
var id = Guid.Parse("1befd5b62b944b4aa600c85632159e11");
var entries = new List<Entry>
{
    new Entry
    {
        Id = id,
        Data = new List<EntryData>
        {
           new EntryData
            {
                Data = DateTime.UtcNow,
                Type = "APPLICATION1_Received"
            },
            new EntryData
            {
                Data = DateTime.UtcNow,
                Type = "APPLICATION1_Validated"
            },
            new EntryData
            {
                Data = DateTime.UtcNow,
                Type = "APPLICATION1_Published"
            },
        }
    },
    new Entry
    {
        Id = id,
        Data = new List<EntryData>
        {
           new EntryData
            {
                Data = DateTime.UtcNow,
                Type = "APPLICATION2_Received"
            },
            new EntryData
            {
                Data = DateTime.UtcNow,
                Type = "APPLICATION2_Validated"
            },
            new EntryData
            {
                Data = DateTime.UtcNow,
                Type = "APPLICATION2_Published"
            },
        }
    },
    new Entry
    {
        Id = id,
        Data = new List<EntryData>
        {
           new EntryData
            {
                Data = DateTime.UtcNow,
                Type = "APPLICATION3_Received"
            },
            new EntryData
            {
                Data = DateTime.UtcNow,
                Type = "APPLICATION3_Validated"
            },
            new EntryData
            {
                Data = DateTime.UtcNow,
                Type = "APPLICATION3_Published"
            },
        }
    },

};
```

I want this to be saved as **one entry** in elasticsearch where ID == `1befd5b6-2b94-4b4a-a600-c85632159e11` and a `data` array that contains **9 elements**.

Im struggling a bit with getting this to work, when trying the following:

```
var result = await _elasticClient.BulkAsync(x => x.Index("journal").UpdateMany(entries, (descriptor, entry) => {
    descriptor.Doc(entry);
    return descriptor.Upsert(entry);
}), cancellationToken);
```

But this is just overwriting whatever already exists in the data array and the count is 3 instead of 9 (only the Application3 entries are saved).

So, is it possible to do what I want to do? I never worked with elasticsearch before so it feels like maybe Im missing something simple here... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to solve it like this:

```
var result = await _elasticClient.BulkAsync(x => x.Index("journal").UpdateMany(entries, (descriptor, entry) => {
    var script = new InlineScript("ctx._source.data.addAll(params.data)")
    {
        Params = new Dictionary<string, object> {{"data", entry.Data}}
    };
    descriptor.Script(b => script);
    return descriptor.Upsert(entry);
}), cancellationToken);
```